# Change the filestructure in linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-management

I am currently using manjaro and I have the following problem.

My root partition is 7gb and my home partition is 100gb big. Now packages always get installed on the root partition.

I tried to resize the root partiton with a linux livecd and gparted but it seems that I can only shrink it.

Is there a way to tell linux that it should reallocate the space from /usr/share to the home partition?

Comment: If your partitions are neighbours, you can resize them to both size. But problem may be in your filesystem: some filesystems don't allow to increase their size. But you always can mount directory from `/home` to `/usr` with `-o bind`.

Comment: I am using ext4. Both are located on the same SSD and they are also neightbors. root is sda3 and home is sda4. But for some reason gparted doesn't allow resizing on root. Could you guve me an example of using `-o bind`?

Comment: You can resize ext4 to both sides. Reboot into live-flash, then shrink `/home` to its tail and enlarge `/`. Use `resize2fs`. Option `bind` of `mount` lets you to make something like "hardlink" to directories. In `/etc/fstab` just add option `bind` to column <options>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Eddy_Em points out in the comments, there is no reason why you should not be able to resize your partition as desired. I recommend you try as he suggested.

Now, another way would be to make your `/usr/` directory point to your `/home`. You can do that using symlinks:

1. Move your existing `/usr` directory to `/home` (if you don't have `sudo` set up on your system, switch to `root` using `su`):

   ```
   sudo mv /usr/ /home/usr
   ```
2. Now, make a link pointing to that directory:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /home/usr /usr
   ```
3. Reboot

---

Using the `bind` option is probably a better idea. To do that, you would move the `/usr` directory to `/home` as shown in step 1 above, then add this line to your `/etc/fstab` file:

```
/home/usr  /usr  bind  bind  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gparted

First shrink and move the partition to the right.
Then you can expand the first partition.

Normally if you shrink the partition it create freespace on the right which is not helpful.  You can move and shrink in 1 step with gparted.  However if you have already shrunk the larger partiton then you need to move it to the right also.

With the resize dialog inside of gparted open
grab the right side and drag it left a big 10gb should enough.  Then click and hold in the middle of the partition icon and drag it all the way to the left.

After clicking OK you should be able to resize the first partition.